# Ruby on Rails - add option to each optgroup of option_groups_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following code:

```
<%= select_tag "Cat", option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :subcategories, :name, :id, :name, 3) %>
```

will product an output like this:

```
Name
    Full
    First
    Last
    Username
    Nickname
Email
    Personal
    Work
...
```

What I need is to append an "All" option to each optgroup label (Name, Email) so that the output is this:

```
Name
    All
    Full
    First
    Last
    Username
    Nickname
Email
    All
    Personal
    Work
...
```

TIA

Comment: What is the desired behavior when selecting "All"?

Comment: I'm using this for an advanced search page. If user selects a specific subcategory (say Username), then I just search for Username; if user selects "All," then I search in the Name category (which would include all the subcategories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld say add a virtual subcategory "All" to each category and handle the selection of "All" appropriately in the controller.

Or (added after comment):

Take the output string of `options_groups_from_collection_for_select`, xml-parse it (e.g. with Nokogiri), find all category-nodes and add an xml subnode of the following form

```
<option value="<categoryname>-all">All</option>
```

and stringify the result. Afterwards you can handle the returned value `<categoryname>-all` in the controller.

Comment: I'd rather not go that route (if there is a way to modify the option_groups_from_collection_for_select) since I use the category/subcategory fields extensively in other places. I'd then have to filter out the All in places I didn't want it.

Comment: Yepp, I understand; what about my alternative suggestion? Might be a bit farfetched?

Comment: Atastor - your suggestion got me thinking in the right direction but I used JQuery to come up with something like this:  $("#Cat optgroup[label='Name']").prepend('<option value="0">All</option>'); which works.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yepp, that will work, too, of course. I am a bit clumsy with all javascript, though :-)Glad I could help :-)